# PHP Webservice with PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I want to retreive some data from my mssql data base using the following code :

```
public function areaGetCities($json){
        $request = json_decode($json);
        $response = '';
        $response->list = array();

        if (!empty($request->language_id) &&
            !empty($request->country_id) &&
            !empty($request->postal_code)){
            $this->db_stmt = new PDOStatement();
            $this->db_stmt = $this->db->prepare('EXECUTE areaGetCities :language_id, :country_id, :postal_code');
            $this->db_stmt->bindParam(':language_id', $request->language_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $this->db_stmt->bindParam(':country_id', $request->country_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $this->db_stmt->bindParam(':postal_code', $request->postal_code, PDO::PARAM_STR, 40);
            $this->db_stmt->execute();
            while ($obj = $this->db_stmt->fetchObject()){
                $response->list[] = $obj;
                unset($obj);
            }             
        }        
        return json_encode($response);         
    }
```

if i print errorInfo() i get

> Tried to bind parameter number 0.  SQL Server supports a maximum of 2100 parameters.
>   IMSSP
>   -29

my problem is that i don't get any result from my database and i have to get (i ran the procedure with the same parameters and i get 2 result).

ideas ?

Edit : I edited my code. Now i get :

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The formal parameter "@postal_code" >was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested >output.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE areaGetCities(@language_id TINYINT, @country_id INT, @postal_code VARCHAR(40))
```

Comment: Where did you see that the `@` is for prefixing PDOStatement parameters? It's `:` for named parameters or `?` for index-based ones.

Comment: Show us your stored procedure.

Comment: the procedure doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `:param_name` instead of `@param_name` both on queries and binds. This is recommended by the [PDO manual](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam).

Also, if the parameter is an output parameter, you should mark it as such:

```
$this->db_stmt->bindParam(':postal_code', $request->postal_code, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 40);
```

The param return will be at the `$request->postal_code` attribute.

Comment: now i get : [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The formal parameter "@postal_code" was not declared as an OUTPUT parameter, but the actual parameter passed in requested output.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a possible solution! Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: i accepted your answer because you told me first to user ":" instead of "@" and that was an error in my code. I posted the real solution :-D

Answer (score 3):

Use `:language_id` instead of `@language_id` as it is also done in the [PDO manual](http://php.net/pdostatement.bindparam). The `@` is used for variables in SQL, so when you prepare

```
EXECUTE areaGetCities @language_id, @country_id, @postal_code
```

It's being interpreted as

```
EXECUTE areaGetCities NULL, NULL, NULL
```

Since the variables (most likely) aren't defined in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that postal_code contained numbers and i wanted to send it as a string because sometimes the numbers starts with 0. I changed the code to :

```
$this->db_stmt->bindParam(':postal_code', $request->postal_code);
```

and it worked like a charm.

Thanks a lot guys !